# Would like to round a JavaScript number to one decimal place but keep getting the trailing zero removed?

Tags: javascript, angular, numbers

I am working with a number in JavaScript from an object and have tried using `.toFixed` and `Math.round` with no luck, my issue is that the zero gets omitted and I would like to keep the zero.

Input

61.999

Desired

61.9 or 62.0

Output

62

Issue is that all the methods I have tried return undesired number (or string): 62
Once I add a new item to my table in Angular and the page reloads.

So far I have tried

```
Number(object.number).toFixed(1)
```

Comment: When I run `const object = { number: "61.999" }; Number(object.number).toFixed(1)` in my console, I get `62.0` (in Edge Version 106.0.1370.42 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 11).

Comment: Well, you're not showing that code, so I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: `toFixed(1)` does what you describe. As you mentioned you lose this formatting after reloading. Perhaps you apply this formatting in some processing which is not applied again by default after reloading? Its anyone's guess without more relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be writing the code to get the decimal value to the function which is being called when you add an item or the page reloads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).